# Is the phrase still "cuantos años tiene" where the age is obviously less than one year?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos

You see the parents of a baby obviously less than one year old. You want to ask how old the baby is. Would it be natural or ridiculous to ask "Cuantos años tiene?" In other words, would the literal sense of the words suggest the answer "none," or would everyone simply understand the question to mean "How old is he", without distraction?

What about changing "años" to "meses" or "semanas" — is that natural or ridiculous?

Answer (score 8):

Where I live, we ask:

- ¿Cuánto tiempo tiene (el bebé)?

"Tiempo" (time) obviously refers to "time of life".

Now that Danielillo has mentioned it in his reply, I have to say we can also hear:

- ¿Qué tiempo tiene?

Both are equally valid, at least in Argentina.

Comment: That seems close to an alternative I'd dreamed up myself: Cual es su edad?

Comment: "¿Cuál es su edad?" does not apply to babies because sb's age is expressed in years and, as you said in your question, that is not the case with babies clearly under one.

Answer (score 6):

In Spain, when it comes to babies, you don't ask how old they are, but,

> ¿Qué tiempo tiene?

As @Gustavson wrote, *tiempo* = time of life.

Answer (score 4):

Another way people asks about it is, "¿Cuánto tiene el bebé?, it returns 14,900 results in Google. ["¿cuánto tiene el bebé?"-Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cuanto%20tiene%20el%20beb%C3%A9%3F%22&ei=56RQY8LOIO7Z1sQPwOGlqA8&ved=0ahUKEwiC3vfB1O36AhXurJUCHcBwCfUQ4dUDCA8&uact=5&oq=%22cuanto%20tiene%20el%20beb%C3%A9%3F%22&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIGCAAQFhAeOgoIABBHENYEELADOgYIABAIEB5KBAhNGAFKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQ6AJY9g9g7hFoAXABeACAAY0FiAHyBpIBBzItMS41LTGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)

Answer (score 3):

Another valid answer is, "¿Qué edad tiene?"

Comment: Maybe "another valid question"? Estoy contigo que lo más habitual es preguntar "¿qué edad tiene?" y esperar la edad en meses o años dependiendo de la edad.

Answer (score 0):

You may ask, "¿Cuántos años tiene?", in those cases without trouble.

However, if you can infer that the baby hasn't reached the year (like, you are seeing him/her and it's obvious because is way too small), is more natural  to ask "¿Cuántas semanas tiene?" o "¿Cuántos meses tiene?".

Also "¿Cuánto tiempo tiene?" or "¿Qué tiempo tiene?" are also valid, as some of the other answers mentioned.

Comment: Note that the OP specifically stated that you can see that the child is less than one year old.

Comment: The right question in all cases is "¿qué edad tiene?". The answer would be in years or months (and/or weeks!).

Answer (score 0):

Las etapas de los bebes se dividen en varios periodos:

- Los neonatos o recién nacidos, se contabilizan normalmente por días entre 0 y 29 días aprox., aunque popularmente también se habla de semanas, 2 semanas, 3 semanas... así de dirá ¿ cuántos días tiene? o ¿semanas de vida?
- La vida del lactante menor trascurre entre 1 mes y los 12 meses. En este periodo se habla ya de "meses", al cumplir los 12 primeros meses de vida es posible hablar de un año o de " su primer añito" de vida. ¿ Cuantos meses tiene?, ¿De cuánto tiempo es?...
- La vida del lactante mayor trascurre entre el año o los 12 meses primeros hasta los 2 años que son 24 meses. En este periodo es habitual referirse tanto por meses como por años. Así por ejemplo se dice "tiene 18 meses" (año y medio) o un año y 6 meses. ¿Qué tiempo (de vida) tiene?, ¿Cuántos meses (de vida) tiene?
- Cuando el niño acude ya a preescolar entre 2 y 5 años aprox., la edad normalmente se expresa en años, aunque es aún habitual escuchar durante un corto periodo temporal, tiene 30 meses, 36 meses, 40 meses... pero abandonando paulatinamente este uso para acabar hablando solo en años o el tiempo o mes en que la persona cumple los años. ¿Cuántos años tiene?, ¿ Cuando nació?, ¿Qué edad tiene?, ¿En que año nació?...